# Are `CompletionHandler` and `CompletableFuture` two different approaches for asynchronous programming in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, future

In Java in a Nutshell

> The callback style for asynchronous I/O is based on a  **`CompletionHandler`** , which 
>   defines two methods,  `completed()`  and  `failed()` , that will be called back when the
>   operation either succeeds or fails.
>   This style is useful if you want immediate notification of events in asynchronous
>   I/O—for example, if there are a large number of I/O operations in flight, but failure
>   of any single operation is not necessarily fatal.

From http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/

> Beside implementing the `Future` interface, `CompletableFuture` also
>   implements the `CompletionStage` interface.
>
> A `CompletionStage` is a promise. It promises that the computation
>   eventually will be done.
>
> The great thing about the `CompletionStage` is that it offers a vast
>   selection of methods that let you attach callbacks that will be
>   executed on completion.
>
> This way we can build systems in a non-blocking fashion.

Both `CompletionHandler` and [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) can be used for specifying callback handlers.

What are their relations and differences?

Are `CompletionHandler` and `CompletableFuture` two different approaches for asynchronous programming in Java?

Or are they used together?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare these? [`CompletionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) is _A handler for consuming the result of an asynchronous I/O operation_, meant to be used with NIO's async channels. `CompletableFuture` is just a general purpose future/promise that supports completions. I don't understand what you're trying to extract from that. Can you clarify?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I would like to know when to use which. Is it correct that `CompletionHandler ` is only used with IO operations and NIO's async channels,  and `completableFuture` may be used with IO operations but not used with   NIO's async channels?

Comment: I don't know about _only_. `AsynchronousSocketChannel` was introduced in Java 7 and its methods ([eg.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-A-java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler-)) expect `CompletionHandler`. `CompletableFuture` was introduced in Java 8, independently.

Answer (score 6):

`CompletionHandler<V, A>` is the completion interface for NIO asynchronous channels.

It was introduced in Java 7, a few years before Java 8 introduced lambda expressions and casting them to functional interfaces (interfaces with a single abstract method), so it has two methods, `completed(V result, A attachment)` and `failed(Throwable ex, A attachment)`, instead of a (now) more comfortable single method.

`CompletableFuture<T>` is an implementation of the `CompletionStage<T>` interface.

It was introduced in Java 8, so its static methods to build futures and its instance methods to build continuations use functional interfaces, with which you can comfortably use lambda expressions.

You can wrap every NIO asynchronous call to use a `CompletableFuture<T>`:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class AsynchronousCompletionHandler<T> implements CompletionHandler<T, CompletableFuture<T>> {
    public void completed(T result, CompletableFuture<T> attachment) {
        attachment.complete(result);
    }

    public void failed(Throwable ex, CompletableFuture<T> attachment) {
        attachment.completeExceptionally(ex);
    }

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, AsynchronousCompletionHandler<?>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    static <T> AsynchronousCompletionHandler<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        AsynchronousCompletionHandler<T> handler = (AsynchronousCompletionHandler<T>)cache.computeIfAbsent(clazz, c -> new AsynchronousCompletionHandler<T>());
        return handler;
    }

    //
    // AsynchronousByteChannel
    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> readAsync(AsynchronousByteChannel channel, ByteBuffer dst) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.read(dst, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> writeAsync(AsynchronousByteChannel channel, ByteBuffer src) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.write(src, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    //
    // AsynchronousFileChannel
    public static CompletableFuture<FileLock> lockAsync(AsynchronousFileChannel channel) {
        CompletableFuture<FileLock> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.lock(completableFuture, getInstance(FileLock.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<FileLock> lockAsync(AsynchronousFileChannel channel, long position, long size, boolean shared) {
        CompletableFuture<FileLock> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.lock(position, size, shared, completableFuture, getInstance(FileLock.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> readAsync(AsynchronousFileChannel channel, ByteBuffer dst, long position) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.read(dst, position, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> writeAsync(AsynchronousFileChannel channel, ByteBuffer src, long position) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.write(src, position, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    //
    // AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
    public static CompletableFuture<AsynchronousSocketChannel> acceptAsync(AsynchronousServerSocketChannel channel) {
        CompletableFuture<AsynchronousSocketChannel> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.accept(completableFuture, getInstance(AsynchronousSocketChannel.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    //
    // AsynchronousSocketChannel
    public static CompletableFuture<Void> connectAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, SocketAddress remote) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.connect(remote, completableFuture, getInstance(Void.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Long> readAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer[] dsts, int offset, int length, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.read(dsts, offset, length, timeout, unit, completableFuture, getInstance(Long.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> readAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer dst) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.read(dst, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    } 

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> readAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer dst, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.read(dst, timeout, unit, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Long> writeAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer[] srcs, int offset, int length, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.write(srcs, offset, length, timeout, unit, completableFuture, getInstance(Long.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> writeAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer src) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.write(src, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    } 

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> writeAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer src, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        channel.write(src, timeout, unit, completableFuture, getInstance(Integer.class));
        return completableFuture;
    }
}
```

A sample usage (for exposition only; no error handling, no disposal of resources):

```
import static AsynchronousCompletionHandler;

AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
serverChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
acceptAsync(serverChannel)
    .thenCompose(clientChannel -> readAsync(clientChannel, buffer))
    .thenAccept(readBytes -> System.out.format("read %d bytes from client%n", readBytes));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (since Java 8), you'll notice that it has a vast amount of functionality allowing a lot more than just callbacks. With chaining, combining and other interesting features.

Compare that to [CompletionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) (since Java 7), and the difference should be obvious.

Nothing prevents you from using both, and it may be even necessary depending on what kind of APIs you're working with, but if you have a chance to use `CompletableFuture`, you really don't need to tack on a `CompletionHandler`.

Comment: Thanks. When shall I use which?

Comment: You'll know when the time comes.

Comment: Please enlighten me.

Comment: I really can't, even if I tried to. It's not a binary choice. But here's one place where you'd *know* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098651/what-is-the-use-of-completionhandler-in-asynchronousfilechannel-for-reading-data